# sigaction - why don't we have to reset the handler?

Tags: c, unix, signals

If we use sigaction to define a signal handler, then why don't we need to reset the handler? If we do the use `signal(sig_no,handler_func)` then we must reset it. Why is this?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void func(int sig)
{
 printf("caught signal:%d\n",sig);
 // Not needed to reset handler. Why? 
}

int main()
{
 struct sigaction sa;

 sa.sa_handler=(void*)func;
 sigaction(SIGRTMIN,&sa,NULL);
 kill(0,SIGRTMIN);
 kill(0,SIGRTMIN);
 kill(0,SIGRTMIN);
}
Output:
[root@dhcppc0 signals]# ./a.out
     caught signal:34
     caught signal:34
     caught signal:34 (3 times signal caught by same handler without resetting handler)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you specify `SA_RESETHAND` in the flags, the disposition isn't changed (and therefore doesn't need to be reset)

If you were to set `sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND` You'd need to reset it because the disposition would be reset to `SIG_DFL` (which is what happens with `signal()`)

Basically, the answer to your question is "Because that's how sigaction works. Its behavior is different than signal".

Answer (score 8):

The real reason goes back to some decades ago. The original `signal()` didn't rearm the handler. It also didn't restart interrupted system calls. The BSD guys decided to have a more "reliable" `signal()`, so they changed that semantics.

Since System V and BSD behaviour was so different, the POSIX commitee decided to introduce a new system call, `sigaction()`, with parameters to modify its behaviour. So the whole reason `sigaction()` exists is to have signal using code that behaves the same across Unix variants.

(Note that the bahaviour of `signal()` can change *even* when using the same libc, for instance, glibc uses BSD behaviour by default, and SYSV behaviour when _XOPEN_SOURCE is defined).

Comment: I would hope it only uses SYSV behavior when `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is set to a very old version, since all modern versions allow the (much saner) BSD behavior, which should be kept.

Comment: Thanks got to know something new.